# Is it possible to make this SQL query faster?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this query, but its so slow... I think the NOT IN function is the part slowing me down

```
SELECT ID  
FROM APPL  
WHERE TRIM(RCNL_ID) = XXX.20191102' AND ID NOT IN  
(
    SELECT ID  
    FROM HIST  
    WHERE SUBSTR(ID, 12, 1) = '9' AND TRAN_STATUS = 'REOK'  
)  
ORDER BY ID;
```

It takes a while to run like 50-60 second is there a clever way to rewrite this so its faster?

This is in Oracle Sql Developer

Comment: which database engine is this?

Comment: @richyen I updated the question its in Oracle Sql Developer

Comment: Remove Order by ID, next try to re write the `not in` to `in`, remove the `TRIM` if it's not required , remove the `SUBSTR` if you can re write it with other logic. And lastly index

Comment: `SUBSTR(ID, 12, 1)` is going to be extremely slow. Looks like your database was poorly designed to begin with for proper filtering. It would help if you included your DB schema, sample data and the output you're trying to obtain from that data, as well as the execution plan for your existing query. See [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952/62576)

Comment: if there is `not exists` in Oracle then use it rather than `not in`

Comment: You may look at function-based index
https://oracle-base.com/articles/8i/function-based-indexes

Comment: Do you have any indexes on the tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a materialised view(mv) or an index..?
https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/materialized-views

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW your_mv
PCTFREE 5
BUILD IMMEDIATE
REFRESH FORCE
ENABLE QUERY REWRITE
as
SELECT ID  
FROM APPL  
WHERE TRIM(RCNL_ID) = XXX.20191102' AND ID NOT IN  
(
    SELECT ID  
    FROM HIST  
    WHERE SUBSTR(ID, 12, 1) = '9' AND TRAN_STATUS = 'REOK'  
)  
ORDER BY ID;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using function based indexes

http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_regular_expressions_tuning_index.htm